# How to copy roles for folders?

Tags: permissions, roles

When I create a folder in one list, I create a folder in other list. I need to copy roles of first folder and paste them to other folder. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create one method that works for me. This method must be called within `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` method

```
private void CopyRoles(SPListItem source, SPListItem taget)
{
        if (!taget.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
            taget.BreakRoleInheritance(false);

        for (int i = taget.RoleAssignments.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
             taget.RoleAssignments.Remove(i);

        foreach (SPRoleAssignment role in source.RoleAssignments)
        {
            //if role contains only "Restricted access" permission level
            if (role.RoleDefinitionBindings.Count == 1 &&
                role.RoleDefinitionBindings[0].Type == SPRoleType.Guest)
            {
                taget.RoleAssignments.Add(role.Member);
            }
            else
                taget.RoleAssignments.Add(role);
        }

        taget.SystemUpdate(false);
}
```